# How to unlock thread in case of multithreading in java

Tags: java, multithreading

Somewhere in the business flow, my thread are locked. So after that everything will be in a waiting position. If it goes like this then how do i proceed without suspend the application.
That means i don't want to terminate the application. Actually its an interview question.

Comment: Actually i don't have much idea regarding this. can u plz elaborate this briefly .

Comment: On Windows I don't know how; on Unix systems, send a `USR1` signal to the PID of the JVM, it will output a thread dump on stderr.

Comment: Can any one plz guide on windows how it works

Comment: Use `jps` to get the Java PID, and `jstack ${PID}` to get the thread dump

Comment: Use jconsole. Start a command window and enter `jconsole`. If you have JDK installed, then it will start the tool you need to dig into the running JVM. You'll be able to examine the state of your threads one by one.

Answer (score 1):

First, and foremost, strongly recommend a good read of the [deadlocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) wikipedia entry. Particularly, the section on [deadlock handling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock#Deadlock_handling).

If this is intended as an interview question, the interviewer is likely more interested in the candidate's knowledge of how deadlocks occur and how they can either be prevented and/or resolved.

Here's a basic example of creating a java deadlock using via synchronizing on a set of objects

```
private static void synchronizedBlockDeadlock()
{
    final Object resource1 = new Object();
    final Object resource2 = new Object();

    Runnable thread1 = new Runnable()
    {

        public void run()
        {
            synchronized (resource1)
            {
                final int sleepTimeMs = 1000;
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {}

                synchronized (resource2)
                {
                    System.out.println("In thread1");
                }
            }
        }
    };

    Runnable thread2 = new Runnable()
    {

        public void run()
        {
            synchronized (resource2)
            {
                final int sleepTimeMs = 1000;
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {}

                synchronized (resource1)
                {
                    System.out.println("In thread2");
                }
            }
        }
    };

    new Thread(thread1).start();
    new Thread(thread2).start();
}
```

First, both threads are (effectively) running simultaneously. Thread 1 will acquire the lock to resource 1 and sleep for a moment enabling thread 2 will acquire the lock to resource 2. This is of course, based on the assumption thread 2 is able to start before the sleep call in thread 1 returns. Now, thread 2 attempts to acquire the lock on resource 1 which is held by thread 1, so it blocks indefinitely. Thread 1 wakes up and attempts to acquire the lock on resource 2, which is held by the thread 2. Both threads are blocked on the other, thus all threads are deadlocked.

Now, this code could be reworked to prevent a deadlock using explicit locks (as opposed to implicit locks on the resource object instances via the 'synchronized' keyword).

See the code below:

```
private static void explicitLockDeadlock()
{
    final Lock lock1 = new ReentrantLock();
    final Lock lock2 = new ReentrantLock();

    Runnable thread1 = new Runnable()
    {

        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                lock1.tryLock(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                System.out.println("Thread-1: Lock 1 acquired");

                final int sleepTimeMs = 1000;
                Thread.sleep(sleepTimeMs);

                lock2.tryLock(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                System.out.println("Thread-1: Lock 2 acquired");
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            finally
            {
                lock1.unlock();
            }

            System.out.println("In thread1");
        }
    };

    Runnable thread2 = new Runnable()
    {

        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                lock2.tryLock(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                System.out.println("Thread-2: Lock 2 acquired");

                lock1.tryLock(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                System.out.println("Thread-2: Lock 1 acquired");
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            finally
            {
                lock2.unlock();
            }

            System.out.println("In thread2");
        }
    };

    new Thread(thread1).start();
    new Thread(thread2).start();
}
```

This approach is an instance of preempting a thread which can deadlock, or breaking the 'no preemption' condition of the 4 [Coffman conditions](http://suneelblogs.blogspot.com/2009/02/list-coffmans-conditions-that-lead-to.html). In effect, the waiting 'tryLock' calls expire after a specified period, preventing the application from hanging indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Use `jps` or Task Manager to get the process ID, then `jstack -F <pid>` to get stack traces and lock information for all threads (including some hints about detected deadlocks).